# What are the vectors of $\mathbb{R}^5$ that are fixed by an element of a cyclic subgroup of $S_5$ (by the usual action)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider $(1~2~3~4~5)$ an element of $S_5$ and consider $G = \langle (1~2~3~4~5)\rangle$.

We define an action, where $(1~2~3~4~5). (x_1~ x_2~ x_3~ x_4~ x_5) = (x_2 ~x_3~ x_4 ~x_5 ~x_1)$.

Basically the action orders the entries of the vector, same as the image of the function is ordered. For example:
$$(1) = 3,~ f (2) = 4, ~f (3) = 5,~ f (4) = 1,~ f (5) = 2\\
(1~3~5~2~4). (x_1 ~x_2~ x_3~ x_4 ~x_5) = (x_3~ x_4 ~x_5~ x_1 ~x_2)$$

What does a vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$  have to respect, for example, to be fixed by $(1~2~3~4~5)$? And $(1~2~3~4~5)^2$?
I am not getting to anything, in fact I arrive that for all cases the vectors are such that all the coordinates are the same, and this seems to me quite wrong. I am making some mistake of logic, and I would like to know which, thanks to all .

Answer (score 5):

If $(x_1 ~ x_2 ~ x_3 ~ x_4 ~ x_5) = (1~2~3~4~5). (x_1 ~ x_2 ~ x_3 ~ x_4 ~ x_5) = (x_2 ~ x_3 ~ x_4 ~ x_5~x_1)$, we have that

$$x_1 = x_2, \\ x_2 = x_3, \\ x_3 = x_4, \\ x_4 = x_5, \\ x_5 =x_1.$$

By the transitive property,

$$x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5,$$
i.e., all the entries of $\vec{x}$ are equal. This is equivalent to saying $\vec{x} \in \mathrm{span} \{ (1~1~1~1~1)\}. $ Since these vectors are fixed under the action of the generator of $G$, we have that they are fixed by all elements of $G$.